# Why am I getting signs of high RF radiation, while the desktop computer turns off?

Tags: rf, high-frequency, radiation

The desktop computer doesn't have any Wi-Fi accessories. The keyboard and the mouse are wired. But even when the computer and the LCD monitor are turned off 
(while the power plugs are still connected), I get a high frequency signal from several accessories.

When I am moving a RF detector (which suppose to detect RF signals at frequencies between 100Mhz-2500Mhz), I get high frequency signals from the wired keyboard, the wired mouse, in front and behind the wired monitor (even when it turns off) and around the desktop case (whenever it turns on or off).

Why do I get those high frequency results?

Comment: Please tell us exactly which device are you using and describe measurement procedure in detail.

Comment: Disconnect PC and monitor from power mains, and measure again.

Comment: Parts of the computer can be powered from the +5VSB rail even when it is powered down.

Comment: Digital systems are often noisy and computers are notoriously noisy. How much RF are you detecting? You should probably expect the about the FCC limit.

Comment: When the PC and monitor are disconnect from power mains,there isn't any signs of signals from the detector.The detector is very simple one,it is just beeping and turns-on a led,when it detect a signals between 100Mhz to 2500Mhz,that all.

Comment: Why do you think that your detector only detects between 100MHZ and 2.5GHz? What kind of detector is this? Especially the beeping part...

Comment: This is,at least,what the manual says.100Mhz-2500Mhz.The detector is just increase ticking and beeping when getting close to the transmitter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your desktop PC is plugged into AC outlet, the internal power supply (PSU) is in standby mode providing +5VSB standby power to mainboard, so the computer can wake up from power buttons and/or keyboard and mouse resume signals. This +5VSB voltage is always on.

To produce this voltage, the PSU must be operating, and therefore continuously switching at primary amplitudes of 200V-300V (DC rectified from AC mains). PSU switching generates noise on all rails and return grounds, switching amplitudes of this scale are difficult to contain. More, when in standby mode, the consumed power is much smaller than the nominal power, so at low load the PSU switchers and inductors/transformers usually operate under very unfavorable conditions, and ripples and ringing from PSU switchers can be even higher than under normal operations. As result, this "noise" propagates along every conductor, including shields of cables that connect mice and keyboards, which acts as antennas.

The same happens in LCD monitor, its PSU is still in standby mode, and still switching and emitting noise.

Comment: As far as i know the PSU is switching at the Khz-1Mhz frequency range,while the frequencies that my detector detected are over the 100Mhz.So,did you mean that the PSU creates a "noise" at frequencies over the 100Mhz which i detect on the mouse,keyboard etc.?

Comment: @xchcui, yes, the edges of voltage switch are pretty fast, and many PSU designs may have substantial ringing, see example here, http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270406/emi-issue-ringing-in-switch-mode-power-supply-layout-5v-3v3/270419#270419 . The signal amplitude is huge (200V !!!), signals are nonlinear, so it should be of no surprise that some higher harmonics penetrate >100MHz area with substantial (mV-level) amplitude.

Comment: What is,more all less,the strength of the radiation that should i excpected from the keyboard,mouse etc. regards to that high frequencies signals?

Comment: If you are not familiar with the amount of the signal strength,may you,at least,compare it vs. the signal strength of the wireless mouse,keyboard etc?What is the ratio signal strength between them?Since,what is the point of connecting a wired computer accessories in order to reduce radiation exposure,while they,also,radiate very high frequencies as the wireless accessories?

Comment: How can such devices pass regular EMC tests? Is there some special, lax standard for PC computers?

Comment: @Lundin , We don't know what kind of sensitivity does the OP's receiver/sniffer have. EMI tests are conducted at a distance of about 10m.

Comment: @Ale,when you said"this "noise" propagates along every conductor, including shields of cables that connect mice and keyboards, which acts as antennas"does it mean,that those conductors  actually transmit to the space RF radiation as the cell phones do or the EMF behave like 50/60hz power line radiation act(not transmit any wave,just alternate a round and along the cable)?